# Modified unrelated files on a specific branch. How to push those files to master branch?

Tags: git

I made a branch for a particular feature. And I had to fix some bugs and forgot I was in that branch. Now I want to push those files with bugs fixed to the master branch and leave the files related to the feature alone in the branch. What should I do?

Comment: have you committed those changes as separated commit, different from other changes in the branch?

Comment: @max630 no I didn't

Comment: Did my answer end up helping at all, Joshua?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by "[stashing](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)" your changes. This allows you to store your changes (without a commit), change branches, and then pop them out.

```
git stash
git checkout the_other_branch
git stash pop
```

Once this is done, you can continue editing or commit them as normal.